# VBA Excel - Count Rows That Contain a Certain Date

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to come up with the correct logic for this:

worksheet 1

```
 A   |     B
------------------ 
test | 01/01/2020
test | 01/01/2020
test | 02/01/2020
test | 03/01/2020
```

So what I am trying to do is loop through column B dates and then count how many rows exist for that date. It would print out something like

worksheet2:

```
 A   |     B
------------------ 
01/01/2020 | 2
02/01/2020 | 1
03/01/2020 | 1
```

I was thinking does column A need to bind each date to a dictionary and then do a count? what would be the most efficient way to do this using VBA

Comment: No VBA required. Just use a Pivot table. And, if that works for you, you can record a macro setting this up.  Or you could use Power Query.

Comment: I agree with @RonRosenfeld. No VBA required for this. Pivottable can easily achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unique Dictionary With Count

- Using the dictionary in the following way, you can at the same time when writing to it, write the count of each key (Key) to its value (.item(Key))

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub writeUniqueCount()
    
    ' Define Source Column Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    ' Write Source Column Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Write unique values from Data Array to Unique Dictionary.
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            Key = Data(i, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) And Not IsEmpty(Key) Then
                .Item(Key) = .Item(Key) + 1 ' Count!
            End If
        Next i
        ' Validate Unique Dictionary.
        If .Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Write values from Unique Dictionary to two-column Data Array:
        ' first column are the keys, second column is the count of each key.
        ReDim Data(1 To .Count, 1 To 2)
        i = 0
        For Each Key In .keys
            i = i + 1
            Data(i, 1) = Key
            Data(i, 2) = .Item(Key)
        Next Key
    End With
    ' Write values from two-column Data Array to two-column Target Range.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
        Set rng = .Resize(UBound(Data, 1), 2)
    End With
    rng.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, something I would have not come up with myself - pivot table seems to work a lot easier... however, I need this solution. thanks for taking the time!